# AZ cli add secret to key vault that starts with a hyphen

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-keyvault

I am trying to add a secret to my key vault using AZ-CLI:

```sh
az keyvault secret set --name my-secret --value "-secret.my"  --vault-name "foo"
```

As you can see my secret starts with a hyphen '-'. This produces the following error:

```sh
ArgumentParseError: argument --value: expected one argument
Try this: 'az keyvault secret set --name MySecret --value {value} --vault-name MyKeyVault'
```

Any ideas on how to circumvent this without changing the value of the secret?

Comment: have you tried `'-secret.my'`?

Comment: @4c74356b41 jup, same result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updating the answer :

Can you try with a "=" in front of the original value

This

```
az keyvault secret set --name my-secret --value="-secret.my"  --vault-name "foo"
```

instead of this

```
az keyvault secret set --name my-secret --value "-secret.my"  --vault-name "foo"
```

Here is the github [**`reference`**](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/2588)

Comment: This did it!
But why this works?

Comment: As to why it works, many things that work with Azure are only known to Microsoft devs. That's their secret sauce ;).